# `QProgressDialog` Not Responding

Tags: dialog, qthread, pyvista, qtpy

I am using `pyvistaqt` and want display a progress bar window when I load data. I have success without using `pyvista` with `PyQt` (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69746072/pyqt5-qprogressbar-does-not-appear-when-run-in-qthread)), however it isn't working when I add `vtk`.

I think something is still blocking the main thread, but I don't know what. Either the progress bar won't show at all, or if it does, half way through the bar stops loading and stops responding. Any help would be much appreciated:

**Setup:**

```
python 3.8.10
pyvista 0.32.1
qtpy 1.11.3
```

**Output:**
[image: demo]

**MRE**

```py
from pyvistaqt import MainWindow, QtInteractor
from qtpy import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Worker(QtCore.QObject):

    update = QtCore.Signal(int)
    done = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def load(self):
        for num in range(100):
            for i in range(200000):
                continue  # Simulate long-running task
            self.update.emit(num)

        self.done.emit()

class Controller(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.view = View(controller=self)

    def on_load(self):
        self.thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.worker = Worker()

        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)

        self.view.show_progress_dialog()

        self.thread.started.connect(lambda: self.worker.load())
        self.worker.update.connect(self.view.progress_dialog.on_update)

        def _on_finish():
            self.view.hide_progress_dialog()
            self.thread.quit()

        self.worker.done.connect(_on_finish)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)

        self.thread.start()

class ProgressDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, title=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle(title)

        self.pbar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.pbar)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint, False)

        self.resize(500, 50)
        self.hide()

    def on_update(self, value):
        self.pbar.setValue(value)

class View(MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, controller):
        super().__init__()
        self.controller = controller

        self.container = QtWidgets.QFrame()

        self.layout_ = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.layout_.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.container.setLayout(self.layout_)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.container)

        self.progress_dialog = ProgressDialog(self)

        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn.setText("Load")

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.controller.on_load)

    def show_progress_dialog(self):
        self.progress_dialog.setModal(True)
        self.progress_dialog.show()

    def hide_progress_dialog(self):
        self.progress_dialog.hide()
        self.progress_dialog.setModal(False)
        self.progress_dialog.pbar.reset()
        self.progress_dialog.title = None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    root = Controller()
    root.view.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"(Not Responding)" in Windows is usually the consequence of a deadlock. Historically, a lot of confusion has surfaced over whether to override `run()` or to use `moveToThread()` when dealing with `QThread`:

1. [You're doing it wrong...](https://www.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong)
2. [You were not doing so wrong](https://woboq.com/blog/qthread-you-were-not-doing-so-wrong.html)
3. [QThread documentation: do not discourage the reimplementation of QThread](https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtbase/+/45271/)

Though both methods are accepted, I chose to use `moveToThread()` because I learned it was best used when you have threads that need to interact with one another through signals and slots (see [QThreads: Are You Using Them Wrong?](https://www.slideshare.net/ICSinc/qthreads-are-you-using-them-wrong))

After careful consideration, I removed the `lambda` from `self.thread.started.connect` and replaced it with

```py
self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.load)
```

which fixed the problem. If arguments do need to be passed, an appropriate alternative would be to use `functools.partial`.

I'm still not 100% sure why this fixed the problem, but I think it did because, in Python,:

1. `lambda`s behave like closures and are evaluated at runtime (see [How to Use Python Lambda Functions](https://realpython.com/python-lambda/)), and
2. creating a signal to a slot with a reference to itself (`self`) doesn't get garbage collected (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35819538/using-lambda-expression-to-connect-slots-in-pyqt))

However, the above being the case, I'm not sure why the progress bar can run part way through (up to 51%) before hitting a deadlock...?

Alternatively, overriding `QThread.run()` works, even though technically the thread affinity would be towards the main thread since `moveToThread()` was not used, so I'm not sure how the signals and slots communicate without issue in this case.

Regardless of overriding `QThread.run()` or using `moveToThread()`, passing a `lambda` to a `slot` will cause this "(Not Responding)" error.

I would love it if someone could explain this!